# Uncaught ReferenceError not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am getting error in console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: check is not defined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

```html
<a onclick="check();">Payment</a>
```

In JS I am getting error due to this line, whats wrong in this ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function check() {
  {
    var label<?php echo $k; ?> = "<?php echo $View; ?>";
  }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: is the function defined before or after the onclick call?

Comment: Whereabouts have you defined the `check()` function? Is it in scope of the `a` element? Are you certain it is included in the page as you're expecting it to be? You also have an extra set of `{}` which are not needed. I'd also suggest you look in to using arrays instead of dynamically naming JS variables by appending PHP content.

Comment: I dont know why but when I am using :
var label<?php echo $k; ?> = "<?php echo $View+' '; ?>"; atleast I am not getting the error. But I dont want to use this way, i mean I need to use $view itself

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a JS problem, an HTML problem, or a PHP problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that you have extra set of `{}` remove the duplicate `{}`, so your code looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check() {
    var label<?php echo $k; ?> = "<?php echo $View; ?>";
}
```

If the problem is still persistent, would be worth checking if you have defined the function before or after the `onclick` call, because sometimes the js might not have fully loaded up (should not be the case, but is worth the check).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
function check() {
  var label<?php echo $k; ?> = "<?php echo $View; ?>";
}
```

Remove double time used {} brackets inside Check() function.
And Check again

Answer (score 0):

You can debug and find solution anyways. But recommended way of attaching an event to a DOM element is using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

That way you'll not be worried about to declare function before or after the HTML element.

```js
document.querySelector('.foo').addEventListener('click', function(ev){
  /*
  * ev.preventDefault();  
  * as we are doing someething "unusual", preventing 
  * default behaviour might be right option
  */
  this.innerHTML = 'Checked';
});
```

```html
<a class="foo">Foo</a>
```